# User configurable CSS colors

Tags: css, configuration

I have been working as a software developer for just over two months.  I was hired at a company that manages cell phone plans for larger companies.  I work primarily on two web applications that work together, the "front-end" where a user can log-in and order new devices, upgrade a device, suspend a device, etcetera.  And the "back-end" where a supervisor can log in and change various aspects of the front-end, (ie. users, cell phone bundles).

I have been given the task of giving a user on the back-end the ability to configure the colors of major ui elements on the front-end, so that a user's portal can be made to match with the company's colors.

I have been playing around with the stylesheet in order to pinpoint where the colors of various elements are set, but I'm not sure how I can implement changes to the stylesheet on a per-user basis.  Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to look into cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to do this.

---

Probably the easiest way is with Javascript. When a user selects a color scheme, you record that and send it to client Javascript (probably via an AJAX request), then the Javascript automatically either directly applies the styles via an inline `style="..."` tag, or by applying classes that directly tie into the stylesheet--which has all the possible colors schemes loaded, which is where this solution falls down a little bit.

Either you're inlining all your custom styles, which is bad practice, or your stylesheet is *way* more massive than it should be. And from the sounds of it, they don't simply want "themes", which are relatively easy, they want to actually pick colors from a color picker to theme the thing.

---

You could also dynamically generate stylesheets on the fly using [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). Have a SASS variable sheet (this is the dynamically generated part) something like this:

```
$color_table_header: [...];
$color_table_footer: [...];

$color_header_basic: [...];

...
```

and fill in those colors dynamically, via some sort of lightweight Node.js server of whatever else works. This would require a little more storage (because you would have to generate a stylesheet per-user per user that wants custom colors). That being said, the stylesheet that you generate for the custom user theme would only have to overwrite the existing primary stylesheet, as opposed to generating a full page stylesheet per theme.

Then its fairly simple: check if the user has a custom style, and serve that stylesheet in addition to the normal stylesheet by modifying the page view.